# Waiting process to return

Tags: c, process, waitpid

Consider:

```
int main()
{
        if (fork() == 0){
            printf("a");
        }
        else{
            printf("b");
            waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
        }
        printf("c");
        exit(0);
 }
```

(from Computer Systems, Bryant - O'Hallaron).

We are asked for all the possible output sequences.

I answered: acbc, abcc, bacc. 
However, I am missing one output compared to the solution (bcac). I thought this output was not possible because the parent process waits for its child to return before printing c (waitpid). Is this not true? Why? And, in that case, what is the difference between the code above and the same without the waitpid line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any way `bcac` is possible. At first I expected some trickery based on the stdio buffers being flushed in an unexpected order. But even then:

The child won't output `c` until after it has output `a`. Therefore the first `c` in `bcac` must have come from the parent.

The parent won't output `c` until after the `waitpid` completes. But that can't happen until after the child is finished, including the final stdio flush that happens during `exit()`. Therefore the first `c` is always from the child.

Proof by contradiction has been achieved... the output can't be `bcac`.

Well, there is one thing you could do to mess up the order. You could exec the program inside a process that already has a child which is about to exit. If the pre-existing child exits before the new child prints `a`, then the main process will detect *that* exit with `waitpid`, and go ahead and print its stuff and possibly exit before the child prints anything.

This is something to watch out for in setuid programs: don't assume that because your program only *created* one child process that it only *has* one child process. If you're in an advanced defensive-code learning context this answer makes sense. In a unix-newbie context it doesn't seem relevant, and it's probably better to just say `bcac` is impossible, even though it's technically not true.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky, but the call to `waitpid` can be interrupted (returns `-1` and errno is `EINTR`). In this case the parent can output `c` before the child outputs anything and `bcac` is possible.

To prevent `bcac` from occurring, either a signal mask needs to be set, or, better, the `waitpid` return value is checked and if it was interrupted gets called again.